# Something wrong when requiring file

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have the following 2 files, first Physics/world.js:

```
var p2 = require('p2');
var pkg_world = require('../redis_pkgs/pkg_world.js');

var redisObjectMap = new Array(); // redis_id - world_id

var world = new p2.World({
    gravity:[0,-9.82]
});

//el piso
var groundShape = new p2.Plane();
var groundBody = new p2.Body({
    mass:0
});
groundBody.addShape(groundShape);
world.addBody(groundBody);

initWorld = pkg_world.initWorld(); //traigo el estado inicial de redis
initWorld.done(function(){
    redisObjectMap = initWorld.valueOf();
});

var timeStep = 1/60;
setInterval(function(){
    world.step(timeStep);
    pkg_world.setWorld(world,redisObjectMap);
/*  console.log(world.bodies[0].id);
    console.log(world.bodies.length);*/


},1000 * timeStep);

module.exports = world;
```

and redis_pkgs/pkg_world.js:

```
var client = require('../redisClient.js');
var p2 = require('p2');
var world = require('../Physics/world.js');
var q = require('q');

var D_object = require('../schemas/d_object_schema.js');


module.exports = {

    initWorld: function(){
        return q.Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            var result = Array();
            client.hvals('d_object',function(err,obj){
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                }else{
                    var tmp;
                    obj.forEach(function(o){
                        tmp = JSON.parse(o);
                        var circleBody = new p2.Body({
                            mass:5,
                            position:[tmp.position.x,tmp.position.y]
                        });
                        var circleShape = new p2.Circle({radius:1});
                        circleBody.addShape(circleShape);
                        world.addBody(circleBody);
                        result[tmp.id] = world.bodies.length; // Mapeo al id del mundo asi despues acutualizo
                    });

                    resolve(result);
                }
            });
        });
    },

    setWorld: function(redisObjectMap){
        return q.Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            redisObjectMap.forEach(function(world_id){
                var object = new D_object({
                   id:redisObjectMap.indexOf(world_id),
                   position:{
                       x:world.bodies[world_id].position[0],
                       y:world.bodies[world_id].position[1]
                   } 
                });
                console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
                client.hset("d_object",object.id,JSON.stringify(object));
            });

            resolve();

        });
    }

}
```

The problem is that in the second file it tells me that world.addBody is not a function but I export world from the first file where that IS a function so I dont understand what im doing wrong or what is it im not understanding from module.exports

Comment: Are we to assume that the first file is Physics/world.js? Filenames for each section may help here.

Comment: yes,sorry I forgot that. I edited it

Comment: I see circular refs. Also - you construct initWorld in world.js with "world" as a parameter, then import it to work on in pkg_world. Wouldn't it make sense to not have the circular ref, and to take world as that param in pkg_world? Perhaps I'm missing something here.

Comment: I used to do it by sending it as a parameter, I only forgot to remove it when I changed it to a require. I thought node supported circular dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The issue exists both because of circular dependencies and because `module.exports` is not set early enough for use in the other module. One simple fix for this is to move the `module.exports` and the `world` declaration in `world.js` *before* the `require()` for `pkg_world.js`:

```
var p2 = require('p2');
var world = module.exports = new p2.World({
  gravity:[0,-9.82]
});
var pkg_world = require('../redis_pkgs/pkg_world.js');
// ...
```

Another option is to instead modify `pkg_world.js` to defer its `require()` of `world.js` to inside your `initWorld()` and `setWorld()` functions.